# How to make ListBoxFor Read only in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have below ListBoxFor in HTML page and I tried almost everything to make it read only but still no luck:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLocations, Model.GetLocationsNotInBuildingList(Model.idCompany, null), (edit ? extraData : new Dictionary<string, object> { { "disabled", "" } }))
```

I have also tried below solutions and none of them worked:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLocations, Model.GetLocationsNotInBuildingList(Model.idCompany, null), new { @readonly = "readonly" })

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLocations, Model.GetLocationsNotInBuildingList(Model.idCompany, null), (edit ? extraData : new Dictionary<string, object> { { "readonly", "readonly" } }))

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedLocations, Model.GetLocationsNotInBuildingList(Model.idCompany, null), (edit ? extraData : new Dictionary<string, object> { { "disabled", "disabled" } }))
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: listbox itself is read only already, u try to disabled it, right? how bout look at this? https://forums.asp.net/t/1840939.aspx?How+to+make+ListBox+Read+only

Comment: What is `edit` belongs to? I think `new { @readonly = "readonly" }` or `new { @disabled = "disabled" }` is enough (NB: `disable` attribute prevents submitting the listbox value).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `readonly` attribute on the `<select>` element in HTML because it doesn't need one: users cannot directly edit the contents of a `<select>` element: they can only change its selection.

If you want a listbox that users cannot change a selection for then render a normal HTML list using `<ul>` or `<ol>` and have a custom style to restrict the height and allow scrolling:

Razor:

```
<ul class="read-only-listbox">
@foreach(ListItem item in listItems) {
    <li>@item.Text</li>
}
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.read-only-listbox {
    height: 500px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
    background: white;
} 
ul.read-only-listbox li {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new {@disabled="disabled" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCities, Model.Cities, new {@disabled="disabled" });
```

It works for me. Thank you very much.